# Java polymorphism behavior

Tags: java, class, polymorphism

If I have a base class call A, two child class extends A called B, C
   B and C both has some extended variables..etc
   What can be done so that when I ask user to input either B or C that I can use a single arraylist to hold both. So that when I need to print it out, find it. I don't have to go through a arraylist of B and and array list of C?
   Thank you for any help!

Comment: Use an `ArrayList<A>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism allows you to use a subtype everywhere a supertype is expected. Every subtype **is** its supertype, so you just create a list of the supertype and you can pass in everything.

```
List<A> myList = new ArrayList<A>(); 
myList.add(new B());
myList.add(new C());
```

On the same note: Lists, other than arrays in Java, are not covariant, hence you cannot put a `List<B>` where a `List<A>` is expected. This is a good thing, because otherwise you could enter an instance of `C` in a list of `B`, which would then throw an exception.

Comment: I'd say less "means", and more "allows you to".

Comment: Appreciate your comment. I got rid of the "means".

Comment: Thank you Kulu, But in this case somewhere done the line can I still split B and C from Arraylist A and get the specific variable only in B or C?

Comment: You can still separate the `List<A>` into a `List<B>` and a `List<C>` by filtering the objects with an `instanceof`-check. Create two new lists, one of generic type `B`, one of generic type `C`, then iterate over your `List<A>`, and add each element to either of the two lists depending on your `instanceof`-check.

Answer (score 2):

Declare an arraylist of type A.
B and C will fit into the list.

Comment: Thank you Fodon, But in this case somewhere done the line can I still split B and C from Arraylist A and get the specific variable only in B or C?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create an Arraylist of type  which is your super class

```
public class A
{
...
}
public class B extends A
{
....
}

public class C extends A
{
}
```

on each of class B and C overide the toString method
and whenever you want to print the arraylist(wether it has B or C in it)
you just do it like that:

```
List<A> myArray = new ArrayList<A>(); 
// Fill it with B and C objects

// Iterate through the ArrayList
for(A item : myArray)
     System.out.println(item.toString());
```